# A problem a day

Tags: discussion

I was thinking about this, and I wondered if I might ask you guys.

How about starting a small problem marathon on Stackoverflow?

Basically, I post a programming related problem (original, not stolen from projecteuler), every day and people post solution the person to post the first, correct solution will be accepted.

And, it would be nice if people could upvote the accepted answer, especially if it was a really difficult problem. The problems will not be something like "Go write an APL compiler", instead, smaller pieces of code (nothing over 200 LOC in Python or something to solve). The problems also will not use anything that is not cross-platform (networking, GUI, etc.) Sometimes, I might post something that's tied to a particular language. Languages can be any, I know Java, C and C++ the most, so, answers in those languages are best reviewed (I'll try to find others to review them, however).

Would this be okay with the SO mods and stuff? Does the community think its a good idea?

If everyone is fine with it, then I'll post detailed rules and stuff.

Comment: Stack Overflow is already running this marathon

Comment: You might be interested in [CodeGolf.SE AKA Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) currently in beta but chugging right along. Come on over, have a look around.

Comment: Wow... that's a lot of downvotes. Just say no for god's sake.

Comment: @Ghaivat: On meta that just means people disagree, not that they think it was a bad suggestion or poorly written: they just don't want it to happen. It's a little strange, but that's what we get for using a Q&A engine for issue-tracker and polling mechanism. Don't take it personally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ !

Comment: Disagree. Codegolf is for the shortest, most concise code and usually languages like J or golfscript with cryptic code like `!@<~+=^*&:;` will win it eventually. What Dhaivat is suggesting is more like a programming challenge, the solution to which could well be given in pseudo code.

Comment: @yoda: Actually, it's a misnomer: codegolf.stackexchange.com is for code challenges (which Dhaivat is suggesting), code golf, code questions about shortening, general puzzles, etc..

Comment: You're right. I read the faq only now. I can't remove the downvote now, but if you make a small edit, I can.

Comment: In practice we are running rather more golf than [other puzzles](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), but contributions from users with [good puzzles](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/298/78) of [other](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252/) [varieties](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/302/) are encouraged.

Comment: @yoda: Small edit made :)